# Power indication

Tags: power, led

I have build a musicbox with an rpi 3+ and added a power button and 2 buttons to turn the volume up and down.

The buttons have LED lighting, I have connected them to GPIO pins but this results in them being turned on all the time even if the pi is turned off. Power button is connected to pin 5 and 6 and then for the led power on the button is connected to ground and 5v pin.

Is there a way to setup the GPIO pins so the lighting only turns on when the pi is on? Thinking of some kind of code for the GPIO pins

Comment: How exactly have you got it connected?

Comment: Power button is connected to pin 5 and 6 and then for the led power on the button is connected to ground and 5v pin

Answer (score 1):

Your LED is connected to power pins which happen to be near to the GPIO pins.  If you instead connect to actual GPIO pins, you can control it -- the internet is full of tutorials telling you how to connect and control an LED to GPIO pins, such as [this one](https://thepihut.com/blogs/raspberry-pi-tutorials/27968772-turning-on-an-led-with-your-raspberry-pis-gpio-pins).

Answer (score 0):

This part

> "and then for the led power on the button is connected to ground and
> 5v pin"

gave me the impression that you are connecting both LED's to +5V and GND, not GPIO, is that the case? if so, this is why they never go off.

I never tested myself, but don't believe any GPIO pins of the Pi remains on after poweroff (see the discussion here: https://forums.raspberrypi.com/viewtopic.php?t=261269 )